# Saving format with Openpyxl. Need to open and save again the file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have an application program "program.exe" that has an excel file as argument:

```
program.exe file.xlsx
```

the "file.xlsx" needs to be modified first. In particular I need to dump a dataframe with some calculations:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename="file.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
list2d = df.values.tolist()
for r_idx, row in enumerate(list2d, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws.cell(row=r_idx+start_row, column=c_idx, value=value)

wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

However, my program does not accept the "file.xlsx" unless I open and save the file manually. I saw some other users experienced the same issue but not solved apparently?

Comment: not sure if it originates with the same issue, but when I've used openpyxl, I needed to save ws/wb content to an existing dummy xlsx file.

Comment: Mm So how you did it? You replaced it ?

Comment: @JPV I cannot understand how to solve it. Could you explain more?

Comment: I have the same issue @JPV did you manage to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on comments:

Yes, program started like this:

```
import openpyxl as xl 

wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

[lots of code to create/format the worksheet]
```

and ended like this:

```
f = '/home/chris/myDir/outFile.xlsx'
wb.save(f)
Popen(['localc', f]) # to open the file after saving, as there's no way to simply open the worksheet/book after creating with openpyxl--`Popen` exists within the `subprocess` package
```

To be clear, `outFile.xlsx` is a file that already exists and is being saved to.

Comment: Linux, but yes.